# QObject::tr() not translating dynamically generated strings

Tags: qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

```
QObject::tr("%1").arg(_value);
```

Here **_value** is of QString type, which is dynamically generated. Is the above way correct to translate dynamically generated strings as in my code it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Of course not, that's going to request and produce a translation for the string `"%1"`.

Comment: So what exactly is the correct way? Any examples?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to do: is `_value` the value you'd like to translate?

Comment: Yes I would like to translate _value

Comment: @Kartik How do you ensure that the set of values that `_value` can take ends up in the translation file and is translated by your translators? Remember that `tr` simply does a lookup in a list. The string to be translated must be on that list *first*.

Comment: @KubaOber `tr()` looks for translations in a list, and if not found then it uses the string given in the code. For example `tr("this string is not in the list")` produces *"this string is not in the list"*. So I don't see why the example in the question won't work. I'm surprised that there's no way to look for the value of `_value` in the list.

Comment: @AlaaM. You should translate whatever you put into the `_value`, at its source. Those are necessarily literals, otherwise you'd get unmanageable mess. Since `_value` contains literals, the proper use of `tr` is to translate them at their location, not after they've been passed through variables.

Answer (score 6):

There are two steps:

#### 1. Make Qt extract the strings for translation.

This means using one of

- `tr()` in a QObject subclass
- `QCoreApplication::translate()`
- `QT_TR_NOOP` / `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP`

`lupdate` will extract the strings passed to those functions/macros, and make them available to `linguist` for translation.

#### 2. Performing the translation (i.e. the "lookup")

This is again done by `tr()` and `QCoreApplication::translate()`. So for instance:

```
// marking the strings for extraction
static const char *strings[] = { 
    QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("MyContext", "hello"), 
    QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("MyContext", "world"); 
};
// performing the translation at runtime
qApp->translate("MyContext", strings[0]);
```

There's a ton of documentation about the whole process, [see here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html).

Comment: How to use QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP in qml file

Comment: Similarly. Use QT_TR_NOOP + qsTr, as described here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html

Answer (score 2):

You perhaps meant to do:

```
QObject::trUtf8(QString("%1").arg(_value).toUtf8(), "dynamic1");
```

You must ensure that your translation file contains all values that `_value` can take with the `dynamic1` for the disambiguation value, *iff* you wish to disambiguate them, that is.

Of course, the `_value` must be selected from a fixed list of strings **anyway** - since `tr` isn't a human translator, it simply does a lookup of the string in a translation list.

So, you should really do this:

```
QString value;

select (variant) {
  case VarA: value = QObject::tr("foo"); break;
  case VarB: value = QObject::tr("bar"); break;
  ...
}
```

That way the relevant strings will be included in the translation list.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to translate `_value` in the wrong place. As stated in other answers, `QObject::tr()` can't guess by itself how to translate anything. It works only on fixed strings. You should mark constants you're setting `_value` to for translation, not `_value` itself.